# Install WinSCP on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line

I tried to install WinSCP, I got this error, `sudo dpkg -i WinSCP-5.17.7-Ubuntu-20.04.deb`

```
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'WinSCP-5.17.7-Ubuntu-20.04.deb': No such file or directory
```

What do I do please?

Comment: Where did you get this deb file? Seems dubious. I've never heard of anybody packaging for debian. Always used via Wine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run that command from the directory where the deb file is located.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using WinSCP on Wine for years and it runs great. Follow these [instructions](https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/WinSCP_On_Wine) and launcher (xdg desktop, icon and script) to install on Ubuntu using Wine. (https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/WinSCP_On_Wine)

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP is not available for Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution. So I wonder where did you get that `.deb` file. The only possible way to install WinSCP is using Wine, take a look at that since WinSCP is only available for Windows.